React Warning: YAxis: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components
I'm encountering a warning related to defaultProps in a React functional component, specifically in a component that uses recharts. The warning message is:
Warning: YAxis: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead.


Here's the relevant part of my component:
import {
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from 'recharts';
import { OutputData } from '@/utils/type';

export function Overview({ data }: { data: OutputData[] }) {
  const yAxisProps = {
    yAxisId: 'strom',
    type: 'number',
    domain: ['dataMin - 100', 'dataMax + 100'],
    unit: ' A',
  };

  const yAxisRightProps = {
    yAxisId: 'abhub',
    type: 'number',
    domain: ['dataMin-1', 'dataMax+1'],
    unit: ' mm',
    orientation: 'right',
  };

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={400}>
      <LineChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={data}
        margin={{
          top: 5,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3 3' />
        <XAxis dataKey='t' scale='linear' unit=' ms' />
        <YAxis {...yAxisProps} />
        <YAxis {...yAxisRightProps} />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Line
          yAxisId='strom'
          type='monotone'
          dataKey='strom'
          stroke='#8884d8'
          activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
        />
        <Line
          yAxisId='abhub'
          type='monotone'
          dataKey='abhub'
          stroke='#82ca9d'
        />
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}


I've tried replacing defaultProps with JavaScript default parameters (yAxisProps and yAxisRightProps objects), but the warning persists.
How can I resolve this warning properly in my Overview component? What is the correct approach to handle default properties in React functional components when using recharts?
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Please consult your favorite search engine before asking for help. Second search result: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/4691 It's a bug and will be fixed in the next version of 'recharts'.

The solution is : npm i recharts@alpha

"Warning: XAxis: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead."
npm i recharts@alpha removed the errors.

"Warning: XAxis: Support for defaultProps will be removed from function components in a future major release. Use JavaScript default parameters instead."
I face this issue.Run the below code and restart your project.Its work for me.
npm i recharts@alpha removed the errors.


I had same problem.
npm i recharts@alpha really worked :-)

This answer has already been given.

I faced the same issue.
npm i recharts@alpha really worked.
But after running this command, must remember to restart your frontend project again. Then, all the relevant errors and warning will be removed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
